# What are the two parallel mappings and Mapping to a tuple of values differences

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading a book about object-oriented programming in python. I read the Example in the book which I cannot understand. 
The example is about implementing **init**() in a superclass(Card class hierarchy). In the first step, a Card superclass and three subclasses are defined that are variations of the basic theme of Card. A superclass has 2 instance variables that have been set directly from argument values and 2 variables that have been calculated by an initialization method:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self,rank, suit):
      self.rank =rank
      self.suit =suit
      self.hard, self.soft = self._points()

class NumberCard(Card):
    def _points(self):
      return int(self.rank),int(self.rank)

class AceCard(Card):
    def _points(self):
       return 1,11

class FaceCard(Card):
   def _points(self):
       return 10,10
```

Then, the following is a class that we'll use to build four manifest constants:

```
class Suit:
   def __init__(self, name, symbol):
     self.name =name
     self.symbol = symbol
```

The following is the domain of "constants" built around this class:

```
Club, Diamond, Heart, Spade = Suit('Club','♣'), Suit('Diamond','♦'),Suit('Heart','♥'), Suit('Spade','♠')
```

Till here I am clear what happens. Now, We can build a complete deck of cards via a factory pattern. This beats enumerating all 52 cards. In this book, 2 mapping methods are practiced instead of a chain of elif conditions.

Method 1:

```
def card4( rank, suit ):
class_= {1: AceCard, 11: FaceCard, 12: FaceCard,13: FaceCard}.get(rank, NumberCard)
rank_str= {1:'A', 11:'J', 12:'Q', 13:'K'}.get(rank,str(rank))
return class_( rank_str, suit )
```

Method 2:

```
class_, rank_str= {
1:  (AceCard,'A'),
11: (FaceCard,'J'),
12: (FaceCard,'Q'),
13: (FaceCard,'K'),
}.get(rank, (NumberCard, str(rank)))
return class_( rank_str, suit )
```

The get method (get(rank,str(rank)) or get(rank, (NumberCard, str(rank))) is the inbuilt function? 
What does it return? what is the inefficiency of each of this code and how each of them works? is there anybody who can explain these methods on an easy way to understand it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get